# What is this common hierarchy mistake called?

Tags: oop, hierarchy

I'm sure i remember a specific term for this situation.

Lets say Mr SO is implementing some Flags.
He has three kinds of flags: New Zealand Flags, Senegalese Flags, and Moldovan Flags.
All of these flags can be raised, waved, and turned into a cape.
So naturally Mr SO begins to implement `Raise()`, `Wave()`, and `Cape_ify()` methods.
Unfortunately he decides to implement each method in each flag,
rather than have each flag inherit the methods.

What is the name of the mistake has Mr SO made?
I'm sure there is a term for it but i can't for the life of me remember it.

Comment: @theDmi :) i'm sure it had a fancy sounding name!

Comment: contract? blue print? method overriding?

Comment: Maybe you mean DRY = Dont repeat your self. But even if he is inheriting the methods he still needs to implement them for each 'land'

Comment: I was thinking of the Liskov Substitution Principle! not even the same thing as I've presented here!